# Reporting weights used in a priori planned comparisons APA style

Tags: planned-comparisons-test

My lecturer wants us to report in APA style the weights we used in a planned orthogonal comparison. I can't find this information anywhere, not in previous journal articles or APA publications. Can anyone help?